# Assign a value to a parameter in application properties before use

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I have a property in my `application.properties` file in a SpringBoot project -

```
app.module.service.url=http://localhost:8090/{DOCID}
```

I have injected it into my Java file as below -

```
@Value("${app.module.service.url}")
private String url;
```

Now I need to replace `DOCID` with some value in my function(i.e-dynamic). How do I get to do this or am I completely missing it?
I am aware that we can do this in case of `message properties` in Spring. But here I have nothing to do with `Locales`.

**Edit:**

There is some value which I need to put in place of `{DOCID}` when using it within my Java implementation.

```
...
public class Sample{

@Value("${app.module.service.url}")
private String url;

public void sampleFunc(){

String str = "random Value" //some dynamic value goes in here
...
```

Now I need to replace `{DOCID}` with `str` in `url`

Answer (score 1):

**Two way binding** is not possible in Spring Properties.It can only read run time and environmental variables.

Please refer following link for more information.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding

Comment: Actually, the config is part of `application.properties` already. I need to set the placeholder value in a function. Will update the question perhaps its not clear.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan -  Edited my my answer based on your edit.

Comment: Actually @Pra Jazz, the fetching part need not be done during jar deployment. It is some value that is built up within the function which is stored in a variable `str`. Then it is to be put in place of `{DOCID}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring UriTemplate for this purpose.

In your implementation class:

```
...
public class Sample{

@Value("${app.module.service.url}")
private String url;

public void sampleFunc(){
 String dockId = someValue; // customize according to your need
 UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate(url);
 URI uri = uriTemplate.expand(docId);
 new RestTemplate().postForEntity(uri, requestObhect, Responseclass.class);
}
...
```

For more information, you can refer :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.html

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ...

```
app.module.service.url=http://localhost:8090/{{docId}}
```

And set run configuration as below

```
-DdocId = 133323 // any number which you want
```

Comment: Is it possible to write more about `And set run configuration as below`? also, can you attach the actual test results?